# Mouse wheel not working properly

Tags: mouse-wheel

I have a 3D optical mouse - Vaio. Mouse wheel works counter-wise for about 5% of times . That occurs more often as the speed of my scrolling increases. Do you think the problem is hardware-related ? Because I bought it recently and it doesn't have any sort of warranty. If not , how could it be solved?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the kind of method used to detect the movement of the wheel, it can be just a piece of hair or a bit of grease obstructing it or maybe it can be also a defective sensor. Try to open the mouse and clean the wheel sensor gently with a soft brush.

This tutorial may be of help: [The illustrated guide to Wacom mouse scroll wheel adjustment and cleaning](http://beeldbuijs.nl/how-to/wacom-mouse-scroll-wheel-adjustment-cleaning/). It's for a different mouse model, but today all of them are more or less the same ;-)